# How to trigger collapse toggle button on Popup windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, triggers

In my web apps are having lots of Popup Window and each window having Toggle buttons are there. 
Currently are all open at initial stage, But I need to collape (Closed condition at initial stage).
Problem is all popup pages are having same class name and dynamic id and dynamic attribute. From my end - we cann't use ID and Attribute.

```
<a class="panel-toggle in" href="#dynamic-value" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
Open/Close
</a>
```

So I implemented trigger function like this for main layout and later that particular pop html page. Some pages are global.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("body .ui-dialog .panel-toggle").trigger('click');        
    });
```

After that above code, on first time load - All are working normal. But i opended second popup from first popup, they collapse all first too. 
Later I tried first popup from individual html and second popup is also another individual - but same error. below code for this type

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).find(".panel-toggle").trigger('click');
    });
```

---

Any idea... Onpage load, I need trigger for that particular page with global code also individual.

Comment: please post your html

Comment: try using `id` attribute instead of `class`

Comment: @Vishalmodi Html code added...

Comment: @VibhaChosla All my id's classes are dynamic. so we can't call id and also attribute too.

Comment: can you create proper working snippet with references files ?

Comment: If you don't want to default open you collapse then set `aria-expanded="false"`

Comment: @AlokMali aria-expanded is not working because in class contain collapse in at default. If we use trigger function, that will solve this issue ....

Comment: Do you want to close it by default? If yes, then remove class `in` as well.

Comment: remoing class name is enough, but in some area I need to open alway. that area no toggle buttons are available. So no need to worry about trigger function for that.